# Why is my array empty after looping?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to write some code that gets random prices from a database until a specific amount is reached. I want it to add the name and price to an array and then print it at the end with `$total_items`, but it's only showing the last item. What's wrong?

```
$total = 0; 
while ( $total <= $amount ) { 
    $query = "SELECT name, price FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    $run_query = mysql_query($query);

    $total_items = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run_query)) {
        $total_items[] = $row;
        echo $row['name'] . ' / ' . $row['price'] . "<br>";
        $total = $total + $row['price'];
    }
} 

echo "<br>" . Total Amount: ".$total;

print_r($total_items);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

variable `$total_items` is defined in the while loop, so it is truncated in every while loop, and `$total_items` will only keep the last result.

try to put it above `while ( $total <= $amount )`

Answer (score 1):

Please define `$total_items` outside the while loop. And double quote properly to print the output.

`$total         = 0; 
 $total_items   = array();`

```
while ( $total <= $amount ){ 
   $query       = "SELECT name, price FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
   $run_query   = mysql_query($query);

   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run_query)) {
      $total_items[] = $row;
      echo $row['name'] . ' / ' . $row['price'] . "<br>";
      $total = $total + $row['price'];
   }
} echo '<pre>';echo "Total Amount: ".$total; print_r($total_items);`
```